# Have electric cars been suggested for those who respond to emergencies on Shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, derabanan, electricity

In a nutshell – and I know this is complicated – the Mishna says that some rabbinic prohibitions were lifted to make life easier on emergency responders *after* they've provided their assistance on shabbos – or else we fear they may not respond (as quickly) next time around.

(And yes, R' Shlomo Zalman points out that occasionally they were breaking *techum deoraysa* in the process ... but ...)

Thus I've heard many rabbis okay with a doctor/nurse/midwife/firefighter/nuclear-safety-engineer who responded to a call on shabbos taking a taxi home afterwards (let's assume that's a *derabanan*), but not driving their own internal-combustion engine car home afterwards (a *deoraysa*).

By that logic ... if we assume (?) that a battery-powered car is a *derabanan*, then they'd be able to drive themselves home afterwards. Ergo someone whose job could involve taking emergency calls on shabbos might seriously consider switching to an all-electric car.

(Or are some derabanans different than others ...)

Is this a practical suggestion? Has it been put out there by anyone?

Comment: A good question. IIRC the Gemmorah paskens that once we rule Pikuach nefesh we don't care for transgressions. Another reason, the fear is that once we open this can of derabanan worms, we won't be able to get them back.

Comment: @AlBerko we allow everything to *go respond to* a pikuach nefesh situation. Once the fire has been extinguished or the patient saved, we generally only allow derabanans for the responder to go home and enjoy their shabbos. On your second point, yes I could hear a rabbi afraid of allowing people to drive after a century of Orthodox Judaism has said "don't drive on shabbos."

Comment: I wouldn't be so quick to assume an electric car is just derabanan. (Surely fewer deoraysas than an old fashioned combustion engine.) What about things like memacheik on the break pads? Other metal parts of the engine getting hot with time? A car is a complex system and one would have to analyze all the parts very carefully to figure that out.

Comment: "Or are some derabanans different than others" Surely such distinctions must exist for something, but even if not, doing hundreds of different derabanans beyadayim is probably worse than one single amira leakum.

Comment: Has anyone suggested hiring a gentile taxi service that uses an electric car?

Comment: I know a cardiologist who bought a Tesla for this reason, and Rav Hershel Schachter told me it's a great idea but one is not obligated to go that far.

Comment: @MDjava thank you! Certainly "great idea but not obligated" for driving THERE; did RHS shlita address driving back home?

Comment: I did not clarify at the time. Also, for those who follow Rav Asher Weiss, it's important to know that Rav Asher holds that all electricity is at least DeOraita, exact melacha pending.